# Сделать сайт по центру экрана целиком

Tags: javascript, html, css

```js
var cvs=document.getElementById("canvas"); // подлкючаем канвас

var ctx = cvs.getContext("2d"); // говорим то что наша игра 2д






var image91=new Image(); // картинка

image91.src="https://cdn.pixabay.com/photo/2018/03/08/21/49/lighthouse-3209985_960_720.jpg";  // адрес картинки

function  q92(){ 
ctx.drawImage(image91,0,0);  

}


image91.onload=q92; // когда картинка програжена тогда и добавляю её












bt10=document.createElement( 'BUTTON'); // создание кнопки
bt10.id='cm10'; // её id 
bt10.textContent ='кнопка'; // её текст
document.body.appendChild(bt10); // нужно чтобы добавилось
```

```css
.container{
       box-sizing: content-box;
       max-width: 1200px;
       margin-left: auto;
       margin-right: auto;          
}

#cm10{
  position: absolute;
  top:200px; 
  left:100px;
}
```

```html
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
  <head>

 <canvas id="canvas" width="1000" height="675"></canvas> <!-- полотно где отображается код -->
 <div class="container">
<div class="img457"></div>
</div>
  </head>
  <body>
   

   <style type="text/css">

   </style>









<script type="text/javascript">


</script>

  </body>
</html>
```

[image: введите сюда описание изображения]Сейчас весь мой сайт расположен в левом углу экрана.Размер сайта 1000 675.
Как сделать чтобы он располагался строго по центру экрана  если в css написать text-align: center; то только картинка будет в центре ,а кнопки нет.Все элементы должны сохранить расположения относительно картинки.[![введите сюда описание изображения][2]][2]

Answer (score 1, accepted):

К контенеру сайта добавте такой css. Вы задаете максимальную ширину контейнера и выравнивате по центру. по поводу text-align почитайте тут http://htmlbook.ru/css/text-align

```
 .container{
       box-sizing: content-box;
       max-width: 1200px;
       margin-left: auto;
       margin-right: auto;          
}
```

P.S. Схематично для наглядности что такое контейнер.

```
<body>
    <div class="container">
         <div>Шапка сайта</div>
        <div>Контент сайта</div>
        <div>футер</div>
    </div>
</body>
```

P.S. Связи измененой задачей добавил новый ответ

```js
var cvs=document.getElementById("canvas"); // подлкючаем канвас

var ctx = cvs.getContext("2d"); // говорим то что наша игра 2д





var image91=new Image(); // картинка

image91.src="https://cdn.pixabay.com/photo/2018/03/08/21/49/lighthouse-3209985_960_720.jpg";  // адрес картинки

function  q92(){ 
ctx.drawImage(image91,0,0);  

}


image91.onload=q92; // когда картинка програжена тогда и добавляю её





bt10=document.createElement( 'BUTTON'); // создание кнопки
bt10.id='cm10'; // её id 
bt10.textContent ='кнопка'; // её текст
document.getElementById("container").appendChild(bt10); // нужно чтобы добавилось
```

```css
.container{
       box-sizing: content-box;
       max-width: 1000px;
       margin-left: auto;
       margin-right: auto; 
       position:relative;
}

#cm10{
  position: absolute;
  top:200px; 
  left:100px;
}
```

```html
 <div id='container' class="container">
      <canvas id="canvas" width="600" height="600"></canvas>
      <div class="img457"></div>
</div>
```

Comment: контейнер в элементе div находится?

Comment: @Ivan912 изменил свой ответ. Для наглядности чтоб было понятно.

Comment: @Ivan912 Контейнер - это нейкий блок какой держит контент в рамках. В данный момент создаем максимальную ширину и выравневаем по центру.

Comment: изменил вопрос,сделал как у вас не не перенеслось

Comment: @Ivan912 В чем ваше вообще идея создание сайты/ "игры" ? Я изменил свой ответ. Еще добавил тут ответ https://codepen.io/john-wick-the-reactor/pen/EJYMEW

Comment: Картинка  правильно перенеслась,но ведь кнопка должна была перенестись  также как и картинка и на таком же месте остаться относительно картинки

Comment: @Ivan912  поправил кнопку вашу.

Comment: Спасибо,вот теперь то что нужно,лучший ответ ваш.

Answer (score 1):

margin:0 auto; и задать необходимый размер